# Oracle endeca property not displaying in jsp ref app

Tags: oracle, forge, endeca, endeca-workbench

I am trying to implement partial update in Oracle Endeca. I have a property named "depth" in developer studio. The full update works fine but in partial update I get the error that "Unable to parse value 15.1 for property depth". Why does this happen. Please ask for any information you might need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property were not showing as MDEX engine had different datatype from the updates. To fix this I used a perl manipulator to format the properties .

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check property type of depth. Also check mapping for partial update pipeline.